# .NET Core : disable parent application web.config inheritance

Tags: asp.net-core, inheritance, web-config, .net-8.0

Is there anything in .NET Core to configure that the child application does not inherit the parent's `web.config` settings?

Comment: can you show an example of that ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside asp.net core there is no such kind of settings which could modify the web.config to avoid the child application inherits the parent's web.config settings.

But inside the parent web.config, you could have below settings inside the web.config to avoid the settings should be inherited by the child one.

Like below:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.web>
    ...your system.web stuff goes here
   </system.web>
</location>
```